# How do I autofill fields with related fields after I select an option in angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In angular, I would like to auto fill fields with the info that comes from the object that I select from this:

```
<select name="nameSelect" id="nameSelect" data-ng-model="nameselect" 
        ng-options="item.name as item.name for item in items">
</select>
```

To my understanding, this then references the object of the item that I am selecting.

If I have input fields like this:

```
<input type="text" data-ng-model="address" placeholder="Address" 
       class="form-control" required>
```

How can I fill the input field with info from the object selected after I have selected it?

Comment: What's the relationship between the data here? right now? is `address` another property of `item`?  right now, your select box isn't assigning the entire `item`, it's only assigning a single primitive property from it.

Comment: address is another property of item, yes. how would i go about assigning the entire item?

Comment: Don't use snippets everywhere unless you learn how to format your code properly with the tools.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are [many forms of `ngOptions`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions), allowing for a vast amount of customization in the way that your dropdown is built, and the way that the properties are bound.

In your case, you are using the second normal form:

```
select    as label     for value in array
item.name as item.name for item  in items
```

Breaking this down just a bit,  you are **selecting** `item.name` and labeling your dropdown as `item.name` for each `item` in `items`.  This means that the value of `nameselect` will be equal to the `name` property of whichever `item` is selected.

To bind the entire object, you can use the first normal form, which omits the `as` clause entirely.

```
label     for value in array
item.name for item  in items
```

this form will **select** the entire `item` object, using the `item.name` as the label.  Using this form, your `nameselect` value will be equal to the entire `item` selected.

elsewhere in the code, as long as you are still in the same scope, you can refer to this entire item, like so:

```
data-ng-model="nameselect.address"
```

Comment: I'm glad this helps;  also, I hope my edits to your question are clear, just to improve readability a bit (also no need to use the snippet option with code that isn't runnable).

Comment: thank you, wasn't aware. this is my first post on stackoverflow.

Comment: no worries, we all work together to improve the quality of questions and provide the best answers possible, so others can find things quickly and easily.  Don't forget to accept any answers you feel answered your question, or ask for clarification on answers you don't understand. We're always happy to help!